# rectangle bar graph filled with color and distance using R (base R or ggplot2 or other package)

Tags: r, graphics, plot, ggplot2

I have following type of data and I want to produce bar graph.

```
Mark <- 1:10
Post <- c(0, 1, 4, 5, 6,
          8, 10,  11, 12,  13)
color <- c(1,0.5,1, 1, 0.6, 0.7, 1,1,1) # 9 intervals between ten points
```

Here ten Mark should be in Post in X axis. Instead of bar height is constant however color coded by color variable. For example interval between 1-2 corresponds to 1 color value while 2-3 corresponds to color value 0.5. Thus for 10 Mark there are 9 color values.

[image]

How can produce such a graph ?

EDITS:

It would be perfect if I could add the color scale legend - color intensity vs numeric value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not perfect, but should get you started:

```
greens <- colorRampPalette(c("white","darkgreen"))
barplot(as.matrix(diff(Post)), horiz=T, col=greens(10)[10*color], axes=F, xlab="Mark")
axis(1, labels=Mark, at=Post)
axis(3, labels=Post, at=Post)
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: @John add in the argument `yaxs = "i"` to the `barplot` call to eliminate the white space between the axes and the bar.

Comment: @James thanks James ! how can get a scale of the color used ?